# I encountered a problem in VS Code with Custom Exception Handling

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I keep getting the following error message in VS Code when I try to run this dart package:

**The method 'errorMessage' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'errorMessage'.
**
Anytime I write this code:

```
void main(){
 try {
    depositMoney(-200);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.errorMessage());
  }
}

class DepositException implements Exception {
  String errorMessage() {
    print("You cannot enter amount less than 0! ");
    return errorMessage();
  }
}

void depositMoney(int amount) {
  if (amount < 0) {
    throw new DepositException();
  }
}
```

What should I do??

Answer (score 1):

Change your `try catch` block like this,

```
 try {
    depositMoney(-200);
  } on DepositException catch (e) {
    print(e.errorMessage());
  }
```

This is because, `DepositException` is a custom exception class.

If you want catch all errors, you can do it this way,

```
 try {
    depositMoney(-200);
  } catch (e) {
    if(e is DepositException){
      print(e.errorMessage());
    }else{
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem dissapeared but after running the programme the error message printed repeatedly and this came up

Comment: Unhandled exception:
Stack Overflow
#0      DepositException.errorMessage
C:\…\HP\DartTutorials.dart:224

Comment: This is because the try catch is inside main() method.

Comment: what if there are multiple custom exception and I don't know the exception to be thrown how would I use the catch keyword

Comment: Answer edited to include that.